# No hyper refs from citation to bibliography using BiBTeX, hyperref and harvard

Tags: hyperref, bibtex, natbib, harvard-style

I am trying to get internal hyperrefs from citation to the bibliography page.
I am using BiBTeX, the harvard package, the hyperref package with optional [hidelinks].
The latter works fine to me on the TOC and sections refs.

I read in hyperref package help that it is designed to work with the harvard package. Yet, there is no further explanation on how to make it work.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[abbr]{harvard}
\citationstyle{dcu}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
This is a test \cite{test}
\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

with test.bib being :

```
@article{test,
title = "Testing and tests",
author = "Test {Tester}",
journal = "Journal of tests",
volume = "1",
pages = "1",
year = "2012",
}
```

I am using an up to date Texmaker editor, running on an up to date TeX Live 2011 distribution, on MS Win7.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `hyperref` package is known for not being entirely compatible with many citation manager packages, with the main exception of `natbib`. (I.e., `hyperref` is *fully compatible* with `natbib`.) While it's true that the user guide to the `hyperref` package notes that the `harvard` package is "supported", the next sentence in the same paragraph of the user guide states that "the recommended package is Patrick Daly's `natbib` package".

Fortunately, you need not change your `harvard`-style citation commands to equivalent `natbib`-style commands in order to get full interoperability with the `hyperref` package: there is a nifty little package called [har2nat](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/har2nat) that performs these translations for you. Thus, if you replace the instructions

```
\usepackage[abbr]{harvard}
\citationstyle{dcu}
```

in your MWE with

```
\usepackage{har2nat}   % loads "natbib" automatically
\setcitestyle{aysep={,}} % needed to fully emulate harvard's "dcu" citation style
\citationstyle{dcu}  % provided by the "harvard" package
```

the hyperlinks from the citation call-outs to the corresponding entries in the bibliography are formed correctly. Observe that you should *not* load the `harvard` package with this setup.

Answer (score 0):

## ShareLaTex

I have used a `mybibliography.bib` item in my files and coded the following command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\title{Technical Report}
\author{Share \LaTeX}
\date{ }


\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
     colorlinks   = true,
     citecolor    = blue
}


% This is used for Quotation Marks only single and double
\newcommand{\quott}[1]{``#1''}
\newcommand{\quot}[1]{`#1'}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

fdadafe

\section{First section}

Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \cite{HARI2008505}

\bibliography{mybibliography.bib}
\end{document}
```

This has worked for me when citing `\cite{HARI2008505}` where `HARI2008505` is an item in my `mybibliography.bib` item